# The integer ababab (a,b>0) is always divisible by 7, without remainder

Tags: equation-solving, number-theory, proof, theorem-proving

The integer $ababab$ $(a>0,b>0)$ is always divisible by $7$, without rest.

I tried to prove this by:

```
Solve[Mod[(a*10^5 + b*10^4 + a*10^3 + b*10^2 + a*10^1 + b), 7] == 0, {a, b}, PositiveIntegers]
```

I expected a `True` as result. What do I wrong?

What does the result show?

$\{\{a\to \fbox{$7 c_1\text{ if }(c_2|c_1)\in \mathbb{Z}\land c_1\geq 1\land c_2\geq 0$},b\to \fbox{$7 c_2+1\text{ if }(c_2|c_1)\in \mathbb{Z}\land c_1\geq 1\land c_2\geq 0$}\},...\}$

Comment: Could someone please include a variation with `Divisible`?

Comment: @Syed Just included.

Comment: Isn't it called a "remainder"? For me, "without rest" means that it does not take a nap.

Comment: "rest" is an the Englishification of the corresponding Swedish term :).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One may regard this question as the test of the system ability of proving theorems, but there is another view to understand what lies beneath this theorem.

Then we figure out that the problem is quite trivial.

$$a\;10^5+a\; 10^3+a\; 10 +b\; 10^4+b \;10^2+b=101010 a+ 10101 b$$

**The simplest proof**:

```
    And @@ Divisible[{101010, 10101}, 7]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

**Stronger theorem**: all common divisors divide the number $ababab$:

```
Intersection[Divisors[101010], Divisors[10101]]
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 7, 13, 21, 37, 39, 91, 111, 259, 273, 481, 777, 1443, 3367, 10101}
> ```

among them $7$, regardless $a$ and $b$ are positive or nonnegative integers.
**Q.E.D.**

Comment: The set `Divisors[10101]` is a subsection of  `Divisors[101010]`  namely `And @@ Divisible[101010, Divisors[10101]]` yields `True`.

Answer (score 7):

```
Reduce[ForAll[{a, b}, 
a > 0 && b > 0 && a ∈ Integers && b ∈ Integers, 
Mod[(a*10^5 + b*10^4 + a*10^3 + b*10^2 + a*10^1 + b), 7] == 0], {a, 
 b}]

(*   True   *)
```

Comment: Great, this works too: `Reduce[ForAll[{a, b}, a \[Element] PositiveIntegers && b \[Element] PositiveIntegers, Mod[(a*10^5 + b*10^4 + a*10^3 + b*10^2 + a*10^1 + b), 7] == 0], {a, b}]`

Comment: My version 8.0 doesn't know PositiveIntegers ...

Answer (score 4):

```
Simplify[Mod[FromDigits[{a, b, a, b, a, b}], 7]==0, {a, b} ∈ 
  PositiveIntegers]
```

> `True`

BTW,`{a, b} ∈ Integers` also work.